# How to efficiently copy lots of Docker images from one private registry to another?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

We have a private Docker registry with lots of images and tags and we'd like to copy all of these into another private registry. Is there an easy way to do this? What would be the recommended approach? Are there any obstacles one should be aware of?

Comment: https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/634 is interesting.